# Using Case When Then to Filter Dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a view for my accounts team to show aged debtors via Excel.

I've got the due dates for all of the outstanding invoices and i want to achieve a 30,60,90 and 120 day breakdown.

My current script is this...

```
CASE WHEN ST_TRANSMONTH = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
     then '30 Days' 
     else if ST_TRANSMONTH = MONTH(GETDATE()) + 30 = '60 DAYS' and so on.
```

I can't ge this to work though, help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please post your database schema, some sample data and desired output.

Comment: CASE doesn't have ELSE IF in it, it just has multiple WHEN (and possible one ELSE)

Comment: You do not seem to look at 30 days, only if it is the current month?

Answer (score 1):

Your math has a subtle flaw in it, in that you're using `MONTH` to check the length of days from transaction date, but as we know, not all months have 30 days, therefore you're going to introduce some areas for discrepancy, which could potentially involve legal issues if you send late notices to people when they're not technically late.

Furthermore, someone could be more than 30 days passed due, but you're not catching it because it's a different month, for example, they bought something on the 25th of last month and it's the 31st of the month now, they're > 30 days passed due, but you're not reporting it.

Instead of month, use the `DATEDIFF` command, that is part of TSQL.  It allows you get to get the difference between two dates for a specified unit:

```
CASE
    WHEN ST_TRANSMONTH > DATEADD(DD, -30, GETDATE()) THEN '30 Days'
    WHEN ST_TRANSMONTH > DATEADD(DD, -60, GETDATE()) THEN '60 Days'
    -- add more cases as needed
END
```

Give that a try instead.

Good luck.

Comment: +1 : Though the pattern `ST_TRANSMONTH > DATEADD(DD, -30, GETDATE()) THEN '30 Days'` will use slightly less CPU by only applying the date functions to a scalar constant, rather than every row in the table.

Comment: @matbailie - I updated my answer to use your suggestions.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this:

```
CASE WHEN ST_TRANSMONTH = MONTH(GETDATE()) THEN '30 Days' 
     WHEN ST_TRANSMONTH = MONTH(GETDATE()) + 1 = '60 DAYS' 
     WHEN ST_TRANSMONTH = MONTH(GETDATE()) + 2 = '90 DAYS' 
END as ColumnName
```

Comment: I have concerns about using month for the reasons that I explain above.  Not all months are 30 days long, and using a month to fuzzy match the days could lead to problems, including potential legal issues if they proceed with collection against a person who isn't actually late, but appears to be on the report.

Answer (score 0):

You only seem to store the month, not the year? Then you can hardly check how many days/months there are between two dates. You should better store a complete date (or at least month + year).

If you store a complete date and you really want to check for 30 day intervals then you can

```
select convert(varchar, datediff(day, st_date, getdate())/30*30) + ' days' from mytable
```

If you store a complete date and you only want to check for month intervals then you can

```
select convert(varchar, datediff(month, st_date, getdate())/30) + ' days' from mytable
```